# How to align a subsubmenu to the right of a submenu?

Tags: html, css

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9wST/) to help explaining.

As you can see when you **:hover Top1 > Sub1**, *Subsub1* and *Subsub2* appear at the right of the Submenu but underneath Subsub1.

I tried solving this with `margin-top: -31px;` at .ulmenuthird as shown here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9wST/1/), but thats just wrong code and gives not the best results. (Sometimes the subsubmenu items have a higher height and sometimes a smaller height).

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey i have had a look and i hope this is what you were looking for.

i have added a div around you subs that have subsubs

```
#container {
    position:relative;
}
```

and change the margin-top to top:0;

```
.ulmenuthird {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    right: auto;
    min-width: 10em;
    top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p9wST/4/

Comment: This is certainly were i'm looking for. When i get home i'll process this into the menu, and accept the answer. Thanks